# Is it possible with a Retry to first make a request several times and after all failed requests with circuitbreaker a fallback?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, resilience4j

Is it possible with a Retry to first make a request several times and after all failed requests with circuitbreaker a fallback?

With the following configuration I see in the console 6 retries and then the fallback url. if I lower the backoff time in the retry configuration I do get 10 retries.
How can I increase the CircuitBreaker time?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    routes:
        - id: route
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: resourceServer
                fallbackUri: forward:/fallback                            
            - name: Retry
              args:
                retries: 10
                methods: GET
                backoff:
                  firstBackoff: 10ms
                  maxBackoff: 500ms
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      resourceServer:
        slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
        slidingWindowSize: 100
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 50
        failureRateThreshold: 100
        waitDurationInOpenState: 100000000
        registerHealtIndicator: true
  timelimiter:
    instances:
       resourceserver:
         timeoutDuration: 100s
```